# What is the RiverPod way to Consume a StreamProvider outside of Flutter - Dart only

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, dart-async, riverpod

#### Working with RiverPod for first time and the Provider concept in general.

**Goal:** Validate the signed in user has an account info **document** in my *accounts* FireStore **collection**.

My code is based off this [flutter/firebase starter architecture](https://github.com/bizz84/starter_architecture_flutter_firebase/tree/91e930280ad5dd2adda90a6f5fb3a7e78934b06b) referenced on the [RiverPod](https://riverpod.dev) site as an example of how to use RiverPod for state management.

I'm using latest [flutter_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) package.

#### My minimized code:

*firestore_database.dart - implementing model/service layers away from ui.*

```
Stream<Account> accountStream() => _service.documentStream(
        path: FirestorePath.account(uid),
        builder: (data, documentId) => Account.fromMap(data, uid),
      );
```

*account_setup_service.dart*

```
final accountStreamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose((ref) {
  final database = ref.watch(databaseProvider);
  return database != null ? database.accountStream() : const Stream.empty();
});
```

#### This is the part I'm stuck on. Everything else checks out. How do I consume the `accountStreamProvider` outside of Flutter in Dart only context? Again, my goal is to simply evaluate whether the stream is empty or if it contains a document.

```
Consumer(builder: (context, watch, _) {
      final accountAsyncValue = watch(accountStreamProvider);

      return accountAsyncValue.when(
        // what do I do here to validate that there is an account 
        // info document for the currently authorized user 
        // using the accountStreamProvider?
        // I don't want to return a widget...
        data: (account) => null,
        loading: () => null,
        error: (_, __) => null,
      );
    });
```

On the RiverPod doc site I've read the "[Reading a provider outside of providers using Dart only](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#reading-a-provider-outside-of-providers-using-dart-only)" reference, however, I'm not sure where to go with it to consume the stream and evaluate data if there is any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation link you posted shows how to get a `StateController` from a `ProviderContainer`.

It looks like the `StateController` class has a `stream` property, so you could listen to that:

https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/StateController-class.html

(I haven't tried that, but that's what I can make out from the docs)

Comment: could you help me please in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68435432/1830228