# Flutter integrating Hive database with Riverpod

Tags: dart, riverpod, flutter-hive

There is very easy way to use `Hive` key-value database on `StatefulWidgets`, for example:

```dart
class HookDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HookDemoState createState() => _HookDemoState();
}

class _HookDemoState extends State<HookDemo> {
  Box user;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    user = Hive.box<User>('user');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
            final _u = User()
                ..nameFamily = 'myname'
                ..mobileNumber = '123456789';
            _user!.add(_u);
            _u.save();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

here we defined `Box user` property and inside `initState` we implemented what's user such as `user = Hive.box<User>('user');`

after that we can use `user` without any problem and getting `already opened` error

now in this current application we used `HookWidget` and when we want to use `Hive` we get error as `box already opened`

`main.dart`:

```dart
Future<void> initHiveDriver() async {
  final appDocumentDirectory = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter(appDocumentDirectory.path);

  await Hive.openBox<UserAdapter>('user');
}

Future<void> main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    ///...
    initHiveDriver();

    runApp(
      ProviderScope(observers: [
        Logger()
      ],
      child: MyApp()),
    );
}
```

how can i create a provider for `Hive` with `Riverpod` and use it into `HookWidget`?

Comment: It looks alright. Why do you say is incorrect?

Comment: About the type inference try with FutureProvider<Hive>. About the initialization, as long as you watch it in a place that doesn't get disposed, the future will be reused. So you can do a ref.watch above the Material app for example

Answer (score 10):

I am using Hive with Riverpod like this.

I am using a named constructor so I can await the openBox call.

```
final hiveProvider = FutureProvider<HiveDB>((_) => HiveDB.create());

class HiveDB {
  var _userBox;

  HiveDB._create() {}

  static Future<HiveDB> create() async {
    final component = HiveDB._create();
    await component._init();
    return component;
  }

  _init() async {
      Hive.registerAdapter(UserAdapter());
      this._userBox = await Hive.openBox<User>('user');
  }

  storeUser(User user) {
    this._userBox.put('user', user);
  }

  User getUser() {
    return this._userBox.get('user');
  }

}
```

Use in a ConsumerWidget:

```
class SomeWidget extends ConsumerWidget {

  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
      final provider = ref.watch(hiveProvider).data?.value;

      ...
  }

}
```